# Are there local maps of simplicial (co-)cycles on $d$-manifolds beyond cohomology operations?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, simplicial-stuff, characteristic-classes, combinatorial-topology

I'm interested in locally defined maps of cocycles/chains on manifolds of a fixed dimension $d$ which are compatible with cohomology. To be concrete about what "local" means, let me consider simplicial complexes representing combinatorial (PL) $d$-manifolds and simplicial (co-)cycles on them. Then, by a "local map" I mean a prescription which computes the value of a $i$-(co-)chain on an $i$-simplex from the values of a $j$-(co-)chain on the $j$-simplices within a fixed constant combinatorial distance. Applying the (co-)boundary map after a local map yields another local map. Using this, we can define a chain complex of local maps and consider its homology.

Cohomology operations $H^j(-, G)\rightarrow H^i(-,H)$ represent homology classes of local maps which are particularily simple for cochains: The value of an $i$-cocycle on an $i$-simplex is determined by the values of the $j$-cocycle on the sub-$j$-simplices. This can be seen by explicitly constructing $K(G, j)$ as simplicial abelian group (let's consider discrete groups $G$ and $H$ here). While I believe it is correct to think of cohomology operations as equivalence classes of local maps compatible with cohomology, they are defined not only for manifolds of a specific dimension but for a much larger class of spaces (arbitrary CW complexes?). Thus, it seems possible that the homology of local maps becomes refined when we restrict ourselves to manifolds of a fixed dimension instead of arbitrary simplicial complexes.

**Question**: Are there local maps $H^j(-, G)\rightarrow H^i(-,H)$ of simplicial (co-)cycles on manifolds of a fixed dimension beyond cohomology operations? More generally, is there any notion of cohomology operations for cohomology functors whose domain is restricted, say to topological $d$-manifolds only?

The hypothetical new homology classes of local maps would depend on a local environment which is more complicated than just the sub-simplices of a given simplex. For different local maps, this environment could have an arbitrarily large size, however, I believe, every local map of chains/cycles can be brought into the following standard form by refining the triangulation of the manifold: The value of the $i$-chain on an $i$-simplex depends on the values of the $j$-chain on the $j$-simplices of its star.

Actually, I already know that there **are** local maps beyond cohomology operations, namely (combinatorial) characteristic classes of the tangent bundle. Local maps for dual $i$-cycles representing the $d-i$th Stiefel-Whitney class are known and precisely of the standard form, with the value on an $i$-simplex depending on its star (those are kind of 0-ary local maps without input $j$-cycle, or, if we wish, local maps in the above sense where we simply discard the input $j$-cycle). Cup products of the input $j$-cycle with such characteristic classes provide further examples. So my actual question is: Are there local maps which aren't generated by characteristic classes of the tangent bundle, cup products, and cohomology operations? Or, roughly equivalently, do all local maps arise from cohomology classes $H^i(K(G, j)\times BO(d), H)$, pulled back via the cartesian product of the classifying maps of the input $j$-cocycle and the tangent bundle?